# set aws autoscale alarm for a percentage increase of CPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS autoscale group. Is it possible to set an alarm for a percentage increase of CPU? For example, if CPU increases 40% over 1min, trigger the alarm? Thus if CPU is at 0% at 12:51 and 40% at 12:52 the alarm will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can set alarms to check CPU average is greater than predefined value for a period of time.
But to check if it increased with precentage, you might need to implement a custom metrics as mentioned below [AWS Blog](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/05/amazon-cloudwatch-user-defined-metrics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can Set Custom Alarm for CPU Load average Increase for `AWS Auto scaling`. Just follow the steps below.

You can find this in `Auto Scaling Groups` select a group for which you want to set alam, further goto `Scaling Policies` click on Add policy then next to `Execute policy when:` click on `Create new alarm`, set alarm for your desired aws auto scaling instance according to your need and set that alarm in `Execute policy when:` and in `Take the action:` you can select Add, Remove or Set to options according to your needs and you are done. When auto scaling group reaches to provided threshold which is given in `Scaling Policies` it will execute policy which you set. For reference you can check  [AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/policy_creating.html)